# Dual booting; Boot drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-partition

I am about to buy a laptop with a 128GB msata (upgrade possible) and a 1TB hdd. My question is if i partition the msata 64/64 (win 8/ubuntu) and split the hdd in half as the storage for the 2 operating systems, will the 64GB space be large enough for the two OSs or should i get a larger msata drive?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is enough for any windows or Ubuntu.

first you install windows & create number of partition you want than you install Ubuntu any of partition size grater than 30GB.